# Drop duplicates in pandas but keep duplicates between years

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this

```
ID     Year    Day
 1     2001    150
 2     2001    140
 3     2001    120
 3     2002    160
 3     2002    160
 3     2017     75
 3     2017     75
 4     2017     80
```

I would like to drop the duplicates within each year, but keep those were the year differs. End result would be this:

```
 1     2001    150
 2     2001    140
 3     2001    120
 3     2002    160
 3     2017     75
 4     2017     80
```

I tried to do something like this in python with my pandas dataframe:

```
data = read_csv('data.csv')
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID'], keep = first)
```

But this will delete duplicates between years, while I would like to keep this.

How do I keep the duplicates between years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 'year' in your subset.

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID','Year'], keep = 'first')
```

```
    ID  Year    Day
0   1   2001    150
1   2   2001    140
2   3   2001    120
3   3   2002    160
5   3   2017    75
7   4   2017    80
```

Comment: Ha, that is too simple man. Should have figured. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda g: g.drop_duplicates()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Year  Day
0   1  2001  150
1   2  2001  140
2   3  2001  120
3   3  2002  160
4   3  2017   75
5   4  2017   80
```